# How to make immutable class in Java with mutable reference with long chaining?

Tags: java, immutability

Suppose I want to make class A as immutable. If A class contains mutable class reference of type B which in turn contains mutable class reference of type C and So on. So should i make deep copy of each and every reference . In such a Scenario how can i make my class "A" immutable with deep copying as shallow copy might break my immutability .

```
class A{
String name ;
B b;
}

class B{
String name ;
C c;
}

class C{
String name ;
D d;
}

class D{
E e 
}
```

//.....So on

Comment: Making a deep copy doesn't make your class immutable. It doesn't stop anyone from modifying the deep copy of the original. A deep-immutable class should only have references to other immutable objects

Comment: It's not clear if you mean to modify or extend the code of class A itself, or to store an effectively immutable instance of class A in some other holding class.

Comment: Make a deep copy of `A`, and don't give anybody `b` directly (make it private, and don't return it e.g. via a getter).

Comment: But to create Deep copy of A , i will in turn need to create deep copy of B as well . right ?